# How to compare Text Datatype in SQL

Tags: sql, text, compare, equals, sql-like

I have a column named filePath, its datatype is TEXT. How can I compare a filePath with another String (case sensitive)?

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM source_code_links 
WHERE filePath = 
      "C:\CtrlSpaceData\CtrlSpace VCS\ba4fe9cbcbdb14a7cbc91fdf65f9e98178afe353\src\servlets\Test.java";
```

I have tried `LIKE`, but it doesnt work as well.
I've also tried PATINDEX but there as error saying function PATINDEX does not exists.

These are the things I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM source_code_links 
WHERE filePath LIKE "%ba4fe9cbcbdb14a7cbc91fdf65f9e98178afe353\src\servlets\Test.java";

SELECT * FROM source_code_links 
WHERE filePath LIKE "C:\CtrlSpaceData\CtrlSpace VCS\ba4fe9cbcbdb14a7cbc91fdf65f9e98178afe353\src\servlets\Test.java";

SELECT *  FROM source_code_links 
WHERE PATINDEX("C:\CtrlSpaceData\CtrlSpace VCS\ba4fe9cbcbdb14a7cbc91fdf65f9e98178afe353\src\servlets\Test.java", filePath) > 0;
```

Are there other solutions available??

Comment: Is this for SQL Server or...? What version?

Comment: Could you please post the entire attempt with `LIKE` as well as anything else you have tried?

Comment: What comparison do you to make between the filepath and the other string? Do you want to ignore case? Do you want to see if the other string is within the specified filepath? Do you want to see if the other string is the specified filename at the end of filepath? Do you want to test whether the specified filepath would match a filepath search pattern in the other string, and if so which Operating System's wildcard symbols do you want to use? Do you want to be able to use different subfolder separators (eg. `/` instead of `\`)? etc?

Comment: These are the things I've tried:

SELECT * FROM source_code_links WHERE filePath LIKE "%ba4fe9cbcbdb14a7cbc91fdf65f9e98178afe353\src\servlets\Test.java";

SELECT * FROM source_code_links WHERE filePath LIKE "C:\CtrlSpaceData\CtrlSpace VCS\ba4fe9cbcbdb14a7cbc91fdf65f9e98178afe353\src\servlets\Test.java";

SELECT * FROM source_code_links WHERE PATINDEX("C:\CtrlSpaceData\CtrlSpace VCS\ba4fe9cbcbdb14a7cbc91fdf65f9e98178afe353\src\servlets\Test.java", filePath) > 0;

Comment: `CAST(filePath AS VARCHAR(MAX))`

Comment: how should i use this CAST function? Where should i insert it? Is it like this? SELECT * from source_code_links WHERE CAST(filePath AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = "C:\CtrlSpace Data....." ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use single not double quotations

Answer (score -1):

You can find out if it equals to other string by using `=` operator or if it's unequal to other string by using `<>` operator. Other options may include using `like` function you've mentioned, but then you need to take some part of the other string by some algorithm and then append `%` symbol on place where you removed characters.